# curl take long time and curlinfo_http_code returns 0

Tags: php, curl

I'm using `curl` but it take long time (about 90 second) and eventually when i check `curlinfo_http_code` it return 0 .

That's not matter for me why and how this problem occur because its just for sometimes .

**I wanna if `CURLOPT_URL` have any problem and my respons take long time just i want `disable`curl instantly .**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"id=$id&amount=$amount&callback=$callback&resnum=$resnum");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $res;
```

Comment: You can use `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` (See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your curl call something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"id=$id&amount=$amount&callback=$callback&resnum=$resnum");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT, 30); 
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $res;
```

for more options, have a look at [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) documentation on php.net